# Wordpress cron running on incorrect time intervals

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

For testing purposes I keep short time intervals for cron and when the functionality is working fine, I change it to the required time interval.
Whenever I change the time intervals for ex: from 'three_days' to 'five_minutes' or from 'five_minutes' to 'fifteen_minutes', the cron is running with earlier set time intervals and not the updated one. I'm totally confused with this.

What might be the reason for this, kindly help me out on this.

This is my code:

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'filter_cron_schedules');
function filter_cron_schedules($schedules) {
    $schedules['fifteen_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 900, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 15 minutes') 
    );
    $schedules['twenty_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 1200, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 20 minutes') 
    );
    $schedules['three_days'] = array(
        'interval' => 259200, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 3 days') 
    );
    $schedules['five_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 300, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 5 minutes') 
    );
    return $schedules;
}
// Schedule the cron
add_action('wp', 'bd_cron_activation');
function bd_cron_activation() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('bd_cron_cache')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'twenty_minutes', 'bd_cron_cache'); // hourly, daily, twicedaily
    }
}
// Firing the function
add_action('bd_cron_cache', 'bd_data');
function bd_data() {
    // My Logic
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix for the issue:
Previously in  //Schedule the cron section of my code, i was checking if the cron is not scheduled, then reschedule the cron. As my cron was already set, the condition was returning false and new intervals were not being set.

```
// Schedule the cron
add_action('wp', 'bd_cron_activation');
function bd_cron_activation() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('bd_cron_cache')) {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'twenty_minutes', 'bd_cron_cache'); // hourly, daily, twicedaily
    }
}
```

The fix is to first check whether the event is scheduled with your time-interval and if not then unschedule the even from previous time interval and reschedule it with our new time interval.
Here is the code for the same:

```
add_filter('cron_schedules', 'filter_cron_schedules');
function filter_cron_schedules($schedules) {
    $schedules['fifteen_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 900, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 15 minutes') 
    );
    $schedules['twenty_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 1200, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 20 minutes') 
    );
    $schedules['three_days'] = array(
        'interval' => 259200, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 3 days') 
    );
    $schedules['five_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 300, // seconds
        'display'  => __('Every 5 minutes') 
    );
    return $schedules;
}

// Schedule the cron
add_action('wp', 'bd_cron_activation');
function bd_cron_activation() {
    if ( wp_get_schedule('bd_cron_cache') !== 'two_minutes' ) {
            // Above statement will also be true if NO schedule exists, so here we check and unschedule if required
            if ( $time = wp_next_scheduled('bd_cron_cache'))// Get Previously scheduled time interval
                wp_unschedule_event($time, 'bd_cron_cache'); // Unschedule the event for that time interval

            wp_schedule_event(time(),'two_minutes','bd_cron_cache'); // Scheduling out event with new time interval.  
        }
}

// Firing the function
add_action('bd_cron_cache', 'bd_data');
function bd_data() {
    // My Logic
}
```

The core logic of this fix was answered by @TheDeadMedic (wordpress stackexchange member).